# Load more for custom query wp

Tags: wordpress

how can i integrate load more button that loads next 10 posts from custom query ?
I've tried with bunch of plugins, css and js ways, but can't seem to load it.
How would you load more posts on load click?
Any tip is very much appreaciated

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row featured-akcije">
    @foreach(get_field('actions') as $action)
      @php($query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'condo', 'p' => $action['akcions']->ID)))
      @php($query->the_post())
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-3 action">
        <div class="box-shadow-posts hoverPic">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 col-md-6 col-xl-6">
                  <div class="action-img">
                    <img src="{{ get_the_post_thumbnail_url() }}" class="img-fluid">
                    <p class="action">action</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8 col-md-6 pl-md-0">
                  <div class="row info-action">
                    <div class="col-md-12"><h2 class="title">
                      {{ the_title() }}
                    </h2></div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 price-info">
                      <div class="divider">
                      </div>
                      <?php if( get_field('price_off') ): ?>
                      <p class="price">price from <?php the_field('price_from'); ?>e</p>
                      <?php endif; ?>
                      <p class="detail"><a href="{{ the_permalink() }}"><span class="nav-border"></span><span>detail <i
                        class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span></a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      @php(wp_reset_postdata())
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented load more functionality for custom query like this:

- Create wp ajax endpoint which is called be javascript on load more button click
- Endpoint gets offset which post to load? For example from 11 to 20 and returns html with rendered posts
- Javascript appends return html to html of the page in proper place

How to create endpoint? Here are examples for creating endpoint and calling it from javascript: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins In endpoint you should call fetching posts like this: `$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'condo', 'p' => $action['akcions']->ID))` with proper offset passed in params, render html template and return it.